# smallest number divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20? Project Euler question 5

Tags: c#, project-euler

I'm currently working my way through the questions on Project Euler and I am on question 5. Is this the best possible solution? Any suggestions welcomed!

```
        List<int> divisors = new List<int>{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

        int n = 1;

        while (true)
        {
            n++;
            foreach (int d in divisors)
            {
                if (n % d != 0) { break; }
                if (d==20)
                {
                    Console.Write(n);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }             
        }
```

Comment: Why are you not checking 11 ? i think your list of divisor should include 11

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know order would that would give?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  Order of what?  If you mean Big-O complexity, it would be O(n), whereas your current algorithm is probably O(n!).

Comment: @phcoding what mellamokb mean is multiply all the prime factors of each number you will get your answer [2,3,4,5,6] 2*3*5*2=60

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise i doubt original algorithm is N!  ,i think it is N*M ( Assumning is N is output Number and M is 1-20) then worst case scenario is N*M right ?

Comment: I was using `n` to refer to the number of input divisors (in this case `20`).  Worst case scenario is that all of your divisors share no common factors, and so you would have to loop 1 by 1 all the way to `n!` before you found the answer.  It isn't a good idea to use the "output number" in the algorithm complexity because it obscures the real complexity.

Comment: @mellamokb agreed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most optimal solution would be to calculate the [LCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of 1 to 20 directly using the standard [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

```
// calculate GCD using Euclidean algorithm
public long GCD(long a, long b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return GCD(b, a % b);
}

// calculate LCM using simple formula based on GCD
public long LCM(long a, long b) {
    var gcd = GCD(a, b);
    return a * b / gcd;
}

// iteratively calculate LCM of 1 through 20
public static void Main(string args[]) {
    long result = 1;

    // loop through each value 1 to 20, and LCM with previous result
    for (long n = 2; n <= 20; n++) {
        result = LCM(result, n);
    }

    // print out the result
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

In terms of complexity, this algorithm is roughly `O(n)` for small `n`.

Comment: this is cool !!! awesome